# WASX7017E: Exception error found in string" " cannot create object name on linux

Tags: python, websphere, jython

I am running a Jython script from wsadmin on Linux RHEL 7 This is the portion where its throwing an error.

SCRIPT:

```
print "Setting WebContainer Properties....."
web=AdminConfig.list("WebContainer", srvr)
pyList = AdminConfig.list("Property", web)

if pyList:
for prop in pyList.split("\r\n"):
   pname = AdminConfig.showAttribute(prop, "name")
      if  (pname == "MaxKeepAliveConnections" or pname == "MaxKeepAliveRequests"):
        AdminConfig.remove(prop)
        AdminConfig.save()

 AdminConfig.create("Property", web, [["name", "MaxKeepAliveConnections"], ["value", 45]])
AdminConfig.create("Property", web, [["name", "MaxKeepAliveRequests"], ["value", 200]])
AdminConfig.save()
```

ERROR:

```
WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "createConfig.py"; exception information: com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException: WASX7025E: Error found in String "{_Websphere_Config_Data_Display_Name=MaxKeepAliveConnections(cells/vmisupcertsap3Cell01/nodes/vmisupcertsap3Node01/servers/server1|server.xml#Property_1453121436178)

MaxKeepAliveRequests, _Websphere_Config_Data_Id=cells/vmisupcertsap3Cell01/nodes/vmisupcertsap3Node01/servers/server1|server.xml#Property_1453196270515}"; cannot create ObjectName.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
targetServerName = sys.argv[0]
servers = AdminConfig.list("Server")
newline = java.lang.System.getProperty("line.seperator")
new_property_name1 = "MaxKeepAliveConnections"
new_property1 = '[[validationExpression ""] [name "MaxKeepAliveConnections"] [description "MaxKeepAliveConnections"] [value "45"] [required "false"]]'
new_property_name2 = "MaxKeepAliveRequests"
new_property2 = '[[validationExpression ""] [name "MaxKeepAliveRequests"] [description "MaxKeepAliveRequests"] [value "200"] [required "false"]]'
for serverID in servers.split(newline):
  if serverID.find(targetServerName) == 0:
    print serverID
    webContainerID = AdminConfig.list("WebContainer", serverID)
    print webContainerID
    foundExisting = 0
    webContainerPropList = AdminConfig.list("Property", webContainerID)
    for webContainerProp in webContainerPropList.split(newline):
      property_name = AdminConfig.showAttribute(webContainerProp, "name")
      property_value = AdminConfig.showAttribute(webContainerProp, "value")
      property_description = AdminConfig.showAttribute(webContainerProp, "description")
      if property_name == new_property_name1 or property_name == new_property_name2:
        print "Removing existing property " + webContainerProp
        AdminConfig.remove(webContainerProp)

    print "Creating property " + new_property_name1
    AdminConfig.create("Property", webContainerID, new_property1)
    print "Creating property " + new_property_name2
    AdminConfig.create("Property", webContainerID, new_property2)
    AdminConfig.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for posting. I need this line of code "newline = java.lang.System.getProperty("line.seperator")"  instead of this line "for prop in pyList.split("\r\n")"